# I have a text box and want to take the value and and print it above the text box with delete button

Tags: jquery

I have a text box and want to take the value and and print it above the text box with delete button. I want to do that with help of jquery

Comment: Ok, well give it a go and we can help if you have questions. We can't write the code for you

Comment: @Aashish Tank, Welcome SO, please read carefully before posting your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this... (check this functions in jQuery docs)

```
// Get the value in the textbox
value = jQuery('#text_box_id').val()

// print it above the text box
jQuery('<span>'+value+'</span>').insertBefore(jQuery('#text_box_id'))
```

I don't know what you mean by *with the delete button*...